# Convert htmlString to Dom object in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I made a http request and received a htmlString, now I want to convert it to Dom object to query its elements.
Thanks for you help

Comment: Why can't you append it to your document and then traverse?

Comment: Show code you've  done so far?

Answer (score 2):

You can create a container object (I've used a div here) and then assign your html string to `.innerHTML` and then you can query the child objects that are created.

```
var container = document.createElement("div");
container.innerHTML = htmlString;
```

The child nodes of the `container` object are what is created from your HTML.

Answer (score 0):

using jQuery you could do something like this:

```
  var yourStringFromServer = '<div><div id="helloWrap"></div></div>';
  var a = $(yourStringFromServer); // create new jQuery instance with string
  a.find('#helloWrap').html('hello'); // find  the helloWrap node and set html
  a.appendTo('body'); // append html to body
```